# How can i get instances for every scope thread in Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

Suppose we have an interface `IService` and its implementation class `ServiceIpmlementation`.

```
public interface IService
{
    int ThreadId { get; set; }

    DateTime CreationDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceIpmlementation : IService
{
    public int ThreadId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDateTime { get; set; }

    public ServiceIpmlementation()
    {
        this.ThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        this.CreationDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

The Ninject is used to bind `IService` interface to its implementation in thread scope like this:

```
...
Kernel.Bind<IService>().To<ServiceIpmlementation>().InThreadScope();
...
```

It works fine when i'm trying to get instances through `Get` method:

```
...
return DI.Kernel.Get<IService>();
...
```

However i also need to get all instances created for every single thread (for running some jobs).

Is it possible to retrieve these instances by means of Ninject?

As far as i can see `GetAll<>()` method declared within the `ResolutionExtensions` class in Ninject library is not applicable in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a thread scoped instance then you have to get the instance on each thread separatly. You have access to the current threads instance only. Getting instances of another thread is completely against the idea of thread scoping.

Comment: Thanks, Remo. And is there any way to examine Ninject instance container content while testing for example? I actually need to get values of Ninject.Activation.Caching.Cache.entries dictionary but see no way to do it so far.

Comment: The ninject kernel itself uses injection internally. You can access the internals by using kernel.Components.Get<ICache>(). But why do you need that? Seems like a smell to me!

Comment: It's not actually. I wanted to examine content of this container just for test reasons.